# Add custom dynamic tags in Sentry.Serilog

Tags: .net, logging, serilog, sentry

I am trying to enrich logs with CorrelationId property, I have such middleware where, I am generating and pushing property to Serilog `LogContext`

```
public class LogContextMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ICorrelationIdFactory _correlationIdFactory;

    public LogContextMiddleware(ICorrelationIdFactory correlationIdFactory)
    {
        _correlationIdFactory = correlationIdFactory;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var correlationId = _correlationIdFactory.Create();
        using(LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", correlationId))
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Having Sentry.Serilog setup like that:

```
 .WriteTo.Sentry(o =>
                                      {
                                          o.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Information; 
                                          o.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error; 
                                          o.Dsn = "<dsn url>";
                                          o.AttachStacktrace = true;
                                          o.TextFormatter = new MessageTemplateTextFormatter("[{CorrelationId}] {Message}", null);
                                      });
```

But I am not seeing CorrelationId in any tags neither in tags section in Sentry UI nor in message formatted text output. Just empty [] here.

MESSAGE

> [] Failed to create identity user for "testuser@me.com"
> because '"Token is empty"'

What did I miss in configuration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is correct solution, but maybe it will help for you.

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/main/samples/Sentry.Samples.AspNetCore.Serilog/Program.cs#L53

```
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {

     var hub = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHub>();
     var _correlationIdFactory = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ICorrelationIdFactory>();
     hub.ConfigureScope(s =>
     {
         var correlationId = _correlationIdFactory.Create();
         s.SetTag("CorrelationId",correlationId);
     });

     return next();
    });
```